# ffmpeg - How to do H.265 encoding on ffmpeg using Mediainfo encoding data?

Tags: ffmpeg, android

This is the Mediainfo File of my encoded video. The original video has multiple audio tracks & subtitles. I want to keep them all intact. Plz note the encoding needs to be done on Android via Termux. Sorry if this is a newbie question. Thanks for the help.

```
General
Complete name                            : TheBatman4KEncoded.mkv
Format                                   : Matroska
Format version                           : Version 4
File size                                : 1 010 MiB
Duration                                 : 12 min 1 s
Overall bit rate mode                    : Variable
Overall bit rate                         : 11.7 Mb/s
Frame rate                               : 351.338 FPS
Writing application                      : Lavf60.16.100
Writing library                          : Lavf60.16.100
ErrorDetectionType                       : Per level 1

Video #1
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : HEVC
Format/Info                              : High Efficiency Video Coding
Format profile                           : Main 10
Format level                             : 5.1
Format tier                              : Main
HDR format                               : SMPTE ST 2086, HDR10 compatible
Codec ID                                 : V_MPEGH/ISO/HEVC
Duration                                 : 12 min 1 s
Bit rate                                 : 8 023 kb/s
Width                                    : 3 840 pixels
Height                                   : 1 608 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 2.39:1
Frame rate mode                          : Variable
Frame rate                               : 351.338 FPS
Original frame rate                      : 23.976 FPS
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 10 bits
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.004
Stream size                              : 9.87 GiB
Writing library                          : x265 3.5+rarbg-HDR-38-20255e6:[Linux][clang 16.0.0][64 bit] 10bit
Encoding settings                        : cpuid=1111039 / frame-threads=6 / wpp / no-pmode / no-pme / no-psnr / no-ssim / log-level=2 / input-csp=1 / input-res=3840x1608 / interlace=0 / total-frames=0 / level-idc=51 / high-tier=1 / uhd-bd=0 / ref=4 / no-allow-non-conformance / repeat-headers / annexb / aud / no-eob / no-eos / no-hrd / info / hash=0 / no-temporal-layers / no-open-gop / min-keyint=1 / keyint=24 / gop-lookahead=0 / bframes=4 / b-adapt=2 / b-pyramid / bframe-bias=0 / rc-lookahead=25 / lookahead-slices=4 / scenecut=40 / no-hist-scenecut / radl=0 / no-splice / no-intra-refresh / ctu=64 / min-cu-size=8 / rect / no-amp / max-tu-size=32 / tu-inter-depth=1 / tu-intra-depth=1 / limit-tu=0 / rdoq-level=2 / dynamic-rd=0.00 / no-ssim-rd / signhide / no-tskip / nr-intra=0 / nr-inter=0 / no-constrained-intra / strong-intra-smoothing / max-merge=3 / limit-refs=3 / no-limit-modes / me=3 / subme=3 / merange=57 / temporal-mvp / no-frame-dup / no-hme / weightp / no-weightb / no-analyze-src-pics / deblock=0:0 / no-sao / no-sao-non-deblock / rd=4 / selective-sao=0 / no-early-skip / rskip / no-fast-intra / no-tskip-fast / no-cu-lossless / no-b-intra / no-splitrd-skip / rdpenalty=0 / psy-rd=2.00 / psy-rdoq=1.00 / no-rd-refine / no-lossless / cbqpoffs=0 / crqpoffs=0 / rc=abr / bitrate=8000 / qcomp=0.60 / qpstep=4 / stats-write=0 / stats-read=2 / cplxblur=20.0 / qblur=0.5 / ipratio=1.40 / pbratio=1.30 / aq-mode=1 / aq-strength=1.00 / cutree / zone-count=0 / no-strict-cbr / qg-size=32 / no-rc-grain / qpmax=69 / qpmin=0 / no-const-vbv / sar=1 / overscan=0 / videoformat=5 / range=0 / colorprim=9 / transfer=16 / colormatrix=9 / chromaloc=0 / display-window=0 / master-display=G(13250,34500)B(7500,3000)R(34000,16000)WP(15635,16450)L(10000000,1) / cll=413,65 / min-luma=0 / max-luma=1023 / log2-max-poc-lsb=8 / vui-timing-info / vui-hrd-info / slices=1 / no-opt-qp-pps / no-opt-ref-list-length-pps / no-multi-pass-opt-rps / scenecut-bias=0.05 / hist-threshold=0.03 / no-opt-cu-delta-qp / no-aq-motion / hdr10 / hdr10-opt / no-dhdr10-opt / no-idr-recovery-sei / analysis-reuse-level=0 / analysis-save-reuse-level=0 / analysis-load-reuse-level=0 / scale-factor=0 / refine-intra=0 / refine-inter=0 / refine-mv=1 / refine-ctu-distortion=0 / no-limit-sao / ctu-info=0 / no-lowpass-dct / refine-analysis-type=0 / copy-pic=1 / max-ausize-factor=1.0 / no-dynamic-refine / no-single-sei / no-hevc-aq / no-svt / no-field / qp-adaptation-range=1.00 / scenecut-aware-qp=0conformance-window-offsets / right=0 / bottom=0 / decoder-max-rate=0 / no-vbv-live-multi-pass
Default                                  : Yes
Forced                                   : No
Color range                              : Limited
Color primaries                          : BT.2020
Transfer characteristics                 : PQ
Matrix coefficients                      : BT.2020 non-constant
Mastering display color primaries        : Display P3
Mastering display luminance              : min: 0.0001 cd/m2, max: 1000 cd/m2
Maximum Content Light Level              : 413 cd/m2
Maximum Frame-Average Light Level        : 65 cd/m2
```

Answer (score 0):

```bash
ffmpeg -i "in.mp4" -map 0 -c copy -c:v libx265 "out.mkv"
```

- `-map 0` From input index #0 (the 1st input) select all streams.

  [Source](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Map)
- For each stream, the last matching `c` option is applied, so `-c copy -c:v libx265` will copy all the streams except the (first) video, which will be encoded with `libx265`.

  [Source](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy)

If you want to encode all audio streams to `aac` rather than just copy them, you would you can add the audio encoding like so:
`-c copy -c:v libx265 -c:a aac`.